# Создать третий список на основе первых двух C#

Tags: c#, list

Есть два List объекта. Они между собой могут быть либо полностью одинаковыми, либо второй список может содержать часть объектов отличных от первого списка. Задача состоит в том, что нужно создать третий список, исключая из второго списка элементы, которые есть в первом.

Comment: в таких случаях изначально лучше было бы использовать HashSet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте метод [Except](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx)

```
var list3 = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```